# When should I not leave on the data integrity on client side in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

I am showing an Edit treenode dialog with JQuery UI Dialog. The user selects a treenode and then clicks the edit link. The dialog opens and displays the name of the selected node in a textbox to edit it.

In my treenode I save the id + name. When I open the JQuery dialog in my GET request I pass the treenode Id  to the mvc controller which gets my the name of the treenode from the database.

Well, is there any reason why I should not get the name directly from the selected treenode which would easen some things ?

Comment: I guess this begs the question: what would happen to your system if they did?

Comment: I don't understand the question. A good question about data validation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156992/client-side-validation-doubts

Comment: Its not about user/input validation. The question is what more is it safe to get the data from the database instead the UI. From what does this depend?

Comment: If you need to validate the data for any reason never trust client side validation as it can be disabled and bad data submitted.

Comment: @Diodeus Well another user could have deleted that treenode in its webclient. That will not happen often but that could happen. In both cases a Sql Update set name = name where id = xxx will be executed with no affected record.. So actually no difference right?

Comment: How about they submit this: "Update set name = name where id = xxx or true". A bit of a disaster, eh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only downside I can see is that, if this system is used by multiple users simultaneously, the tree node might have been changed or even deleted in the database between the initial load and the time you want to rename it. By getting fresh data from the database you can notify the user about this up front.

If this is not an issue for you, go for it.